# Centering divs in a row

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a row of divs with classes called card. There can be up to three cards within a row. Each card has a width of 33%.

The html looks like...

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="card">card</div>
  <div class="card">card 2</div>
  <div class="card">card 3</div>
</div>

<br>
<br>

<div class="row">
  <div class="card">card</div>
  <div class="card">card 2</div> 
</div>
```

The CSS looks like...

```
.row {
  padding: 20px; 
}

.card {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  border: solid 1px black;
  position: relative;
}
```

I've also created a codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yVjYxE).

What I want is to center these cards if there are less than 3 cards in a row. 
How do I do this?

Normally 3 cards in a row would look like...

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                             |                                |                          |
|                             |                                |                          |
|                             |                                |                          |
|                             |                                |                          |
|        card                 |            card                |        card              |
|                             |                                |                          |
|                             |                                |                          |
|                             |                                |                          |
|                             |                                |                          |
|                             |                                |                          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When we have 2 cards in a row it looks like...

```
--------------------------------------------------------
|                        |                             | 
|                        |                             | 
|                        |                             | 
|                        |                             | 
|                        |                             | 
|         card           |            card             | 
|                        |                             | 
|                        |                             | 
|                        |                             | 
|                        |                             | 
--------------------------------------------------------
```

We want the 2 cards to be centered like so...

```
                   -----------------------------------------------------
                   |                        |                          | 
                   |                        |                          | 
                   |                        |                          | 
                   |                        |                          | 
                   |                        |                          | 
                   |         card           |          card            | 
                   |                        |                          | 
                   |                        |                          | 
                   |                        |                          | 
                   |                        |                          | 
                   -----------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **css3 [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) concept** concept for this,set the **display** property of your parent tag(.row) to **flex**.and then use **justify-content** property and set it's value to **center**.

```css
.row {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content :center;
}

.card {
  width: 33%;
  height:100px;
  /*float: left;*/
  border: solid 1px black;
  /*position: relative;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="card">card</div>
  <div class="card">card 2</div>
  <div class="card">card 3</div>
</div>

<br>
<br>

<div class="row">
  <div class="card">card</div>
  <div class="card">card 2</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm this works really well. The only problem is that this solution isn't mobile friendly for me. In smaller widths the boxes overlap when in reality I would like for them stack on top of one another.

Answer (score 3):

Use `inline-block` instead of float and `text-align: center;`

```
.row {
  padding: 20px; 
  text-align: center;
}

.card {
  width: 33%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PbeZgd

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using display:flex and justify-content:center for this

check this snippet

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.card {
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px dashed;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="card">card</div>
  <div class="card">card 2</div>
  <div class="card">card 3</div>
</div>

<br>
<br>

<div class="row">
  <div class="card">card</div>
  <div class="card">card 2</div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I would recommend giving flexbox a shot, too. It's a great skill to have!